# Setting up a project in PyCharm using the Anaconda base virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm trying to set up a Python project in PyCharm. I have Anaconda installed, and I want to make use of the Anaconda base virtual environment as the interpreter of the project. Is this possible? Going through the setup process I see only the other virtual environments, not the base environment.

Comment: You could add it as an existing System Interpreter but it is not recommended since base venv contains huge amount of packages

Comment: _I want to make use of the Anaconda base virtual environment as the interpreter of the project. Is this possible?_ Yes it's possible, but you shouldn't, for a variety of reasons. Just create a new environment for each project/program.

Comment: The reason I wanted to make use of the base environment is that I wanted to avoid reinstalling all the packages/libraries for each new project. Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to figure this out. In PyCharm I'm simply selecting an existing interpreter (instead of creating a new environment), and pointing to the python executable in the Anaconda install folder.